# how to get object from vars in ForEach Controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

say I have set a list on a post beanshell processor of last request.

```
 List list = Arrays.asList("a","b");
 vars.putObject("list", list);
```

how can I apply each of the list value onto request within a ForEach Contoller ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) cannot operate on objects, you have to create [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of:

   ```
   var_1=a
   var_2=b
   ```

   You can create JMeter Variables using `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

   ```
   vars.put("var_1", "a");
   vars.put("var_2", "b");
   ```

   [image]
2. Then you can configure ForEach Controllers to consume `var` prefix and store the output into `${current_var}` JMeter Variable:

   [image]
3. That's it, the ForEach Controller will iterate the created variables:

   [image]

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as [Groovy performance is much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). Moreover Groovy is more "modern" language, it supports all the new Java features and [provides extra functionality](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of standard Java SDK.